# Simulate pressing "yes" after few "Enter" within bash command

Tags: python, bash, shell

While generating key/cert you should press few times 'enter' and in the very end press "yes". How to do it in code like this?

```
buildkey = ["printf '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n ' | /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/build-key"]
runBuildKey = subprocess.Popen(buildkey, shell=True )
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the square brackets are doing there, but apart from that, the approach looks like it has legs; what happens when you try your version?

Comment: This is the wrong place to start out-of-the-gate. You should be editing your `openssl.cnf` (since you're using easy-rsa, you'll have one) to get all its input from environment variables, so you don't need to "press enter" on stdin at all.

Comment: @ Charles Duffy , what do you mean :"You should be editing your openssl.cnf"

Comment: In `/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa`, see the file `openssl.cnf`?

Comment: I still don`t see where I could switch "y/n" prompt off in openssl.cnf ..

Comment: It's covered in the OpenSSL docs.

Comment: ok,thanks, I will learn docs but if not editing is it any way to confirm yes in command itself?

Comment: Of course -- you could put `yes\n` in your format string, but that's silly and fragile and likely to break if your openssl.cnf file ever changes or you install a new openssl version.

Comment: Also, just because this works with openssl doesn't mean it'll work in other cases where you want to do something similar. Programs that are actually written with security in mind get passwords and similar sensitive content direct from the TTY, not from stdin, so piping to them doesn't work.

Comment: Also, it's silly to run a shell command here instead of passing your string with a bunch of newlines and so forth to `communicate()` to be stdin.

Comment: Could you please place an example of code in situation like mine?

Comment: Did you not see my last example? Sure, I'm not sure I got the number of `''`s right, since that depends on how many prompts you want to press enter at prior to the one where you want the `yes`, but it's correct in all essentials.

Comment: Really, though, if you want defaults to absolutely *everything* (other than the "proceed?" question at the end which it moots), just use `-batch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to edit stdin at all here. Instead, open up your `openssl.cnf`, and modify it to get all the input you need from the environment, like so:

```
[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName_default             = $ENV::SSL_countryName
stateOrProvinceName_default     = $ENV::SSL_stateOrProvinenceName
```

...and so forth. Once this is done, set the variables in your environment before calling `build-key` with the argument `-batch`. In bash, that might look like so:

```
SSL_countryName=foo SSL_stateOrProvinenceName=bar build-key -batch </dev/null
```

Alternately, in Python, you can do the same thing via arguments to `subprocess.Popen`:

```
subprocess.call(['/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/build-key', '-batch'], env={
    'SSL_countryName': 'foo',
    'SSL_stateOrProvinenceName': 'bar',
    # ...and so forth for any other $ENV::* setting you want to override
}, stdin=open('/dev/null', 'r'))
```

---

However, if you *really* want to pass a custom stream through for stdin, you can do that -- without any shell pipeline at all:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/build-key'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate('\n'.join(['', '', '', '', '', 'yes', '']))
#                        ^^
#   use one of these for each item you want to press enter to before the "yes"
```